# PrimeNG p-calendar border is not implement

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG to implement a time picker to enter the start and end times. I implement the p-calendar time picker and output the result, you can see that the border of the time picker is not displayed well.

Here is my HTML code

```
  <div class="overtime-log-form-working-hours">
    <div class="field">
      <label for="start_time" class="col-12 md-2 pb-0">Start Time</label>
      <div class="col-12">
        <p-calendar formControlName="start_time" id="start_time" name="start_time" [(ngModel)]="model.start_time"
          (onBlur)="_formHelper.validateControl('start_time')" [timeOnly]="true" placeholder="00:00">
        </p-calendar>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="end_time" class="col-12 md-2 pb-0">End Time</label>
      <div class="col-12">
        <p-calendar class="border" formControlName="end_time" id="end_time" name="end_time" [(ngModel)]="model.end_time"
          (onBlur)="_formHelper.validateControl('end_time')" [timeOnly]="true" placeholder="00:00">
        </p-calendar>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

.SCSS

```
:host ::ng-deep .overtime-log-form {
  .col-12 {
    padding: 0;
  }
  &-working-hours {
    display: flex;
    .field {
      &:first-child {
        margin-right: 2.0625rem;
      }
      .p-calendar{
        max-width: 81px;
      }
    }
  }
  #reason {
    min-height: 7.6rem;
    max-height: 7.6rem;
    overflow-y: auto!important;
  }
}
```

[you can see an example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M0XC.png)

Comment: no! I didn't add anything to styles.css

Comment: these things are already there! 
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",

              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
            ]

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-yyjqvi?file=src/app/app.component.html Here is the URL

Comment: In this demo its working right.

Comment: Yes! but not in my local. I think the problem is in my form component. @GRD

Comment: I am curious what version of PrimeNG you are using.  The Stack-blitz is version 12, not 13.